# Meteor.users maintaining users

Tags: meteor

I have a Meteor app where I need to:

1. Create / update app users including their name, username and password. So I was wondering if first is it possible to do so while login to the app as a Meteor user? In other words is it possible to create / update other app users while logging in as an app user? I've tried to search for an example / how to but couldn't find any so any help will be highly appreciated.
2. Add custom fields to Meteor.users document (ex. User type(accountant / sales...etc), Phone...etc)? After research couldn't find any example except on how to update Meteor.users profile in update only, but couldn't find how to do so when creating the new user, so any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add fields to user simply use `onCreateUser` function

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(user) {
  user.type = "customer";
  user.phone = "123456789";
   //etc
  return user;
});
```

And I didn't understand first question, but you can update user data by making query, such as:
`Meteor.users.update({_id:this._id},{$addToSet~});`