# Storing per-user data in Meteor

Tags: meteor, data-modeling

I want to store information for every logged in user in my meteor app, such as their profile picture, bio, ect. But if I try to do something like Meteor.user().picLink = "..."; it appears to get erased on every subsequent call to Meteor.user(). I assume this means I'm not supposed to store extra data directly on the user object like that.

The only response to that that I can think of is to have a separate collection with user data in it. But that seems like it would be hard to keep consistent with Meteor.users. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All user accounts come with an automatically published `profile` field which you can update like so:

```js
var userId = Meteor.userId();
var url = 'http://example.com/kittens.jpg';
Meteor.users.update(userId, {$set: {'profile.photo': url});
```

That will update the underlying database and persist across connections.

As I point out [here](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes) you should be aware that the profile object is currently editable by default even when the `insecure` package has been removed. This means any user can open up the console and modify his/her profile.

A better approach is to deny the updates and to use a method instead:

#### client

```js
var url = 'http://example.com/kittens.jpg';
Meteor.call('update.photo', url);
```

#### server

```js
Meteor.users.deny({
  update: function() {return true;}
});

Meteor.methods({
  'update.photo': function(url) {
    check(url, String);
    Meteor.users.update(this.userId, {$set: {'profile.photo': url}});
  }
});
```

Comment: Let me just add this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26699783/meteor-users-maintaining-users/26700579#26700579, it explains how to add fields at user creation, it might come in handy in this case too.

Comment: Cool, but do I have to use .update() or can I just access user.profile directly?

Comment: You need to actually call `update` if you want it to modify the DB, otherwise you are only setting it in memory.

Comment: If it is more than just profile data (sayor comments for example) would it be best to just connect the Meteor user to this or the other way around (or some other option)?